# RendererFactory2 in tests fails

Tags: angular, jasmine

I have a preferences service in an angular 5 application that loads `'light-theme'` or `'dark-theme'` from local storage and adds a class to the body accordingly.

```
import {Injectable, OnDestroy, Renderer2, RendererFactory2} from '@angular/core';
// ...

@Injectable()
@AutoUnsubscribe()
export class UiPreferencesService implements OnDestroy {

private renderer: Renderer2;

    constructor(rendererFactory: RendererFactory2) {
        this.renderer = rendererFactory.createRenderer(null, null);
        this.loadPrefs();
    }
  // moar code
    private emitTheme(theme) {
        this.currentThemeSubject.next(theme);
        this.renderer.addClass(document.body, theme);
        this.renderer.removeClass(document.body, this.notCurrentTheme());
    }
}
```

I had to use the `RendererFactory2` since I'm using the renderer in my service. The issue I'm having is in my tests:

`Cannot call addClass on null`

How can I get the RendererFactory2 to work in my tests.

Answer (score 2):

In your providers you need to mock RendererFactory2 and set create renderer to receive an anonymous function:

```
mockProvider(RendererFactory2, {
     createRenderer: () => renderer2
}),
```

renderer2 should have the functions you need:

```
let renderer2: Renderer2 = {
        addClass: jasmine.createSpy('addClass'),
        removeClass: jasmine.createSpy('removeClass'),
    } as unknown as Renderer2;
```

Then, use renderer2 in your test:

```
expect(renderer2.addClass).toHaveBeenCalledWith(document.body, 'your-class');
```

So something like this:

```
describe('Some name', () => {
    let renderer2: Renderer2 = {
        addClass: jasmine.createSpy('addClass'),
        removeClass: jasmine.createSpy('removeClass'),
    } as unknown as Renderer2;

    beforeEach(async(() => {
        TestBed.configureTestingModule({
            imports: [],
            providers: [
                ...your providers...,
                mockProvider(RendererFactory2, {
                    createRenderer: () => renderer2
                }),
            ],
        }).compileComponents();
    }));

    describe('adding a class to body', () => {
        it('renderer addClass should be called', () => {
            //your code which triggers class adding
            expect(renderer2.addClass).toHaveBeenCalledWith(document.body, 'your-class');
        });
```

Comment: what is `mockProvider` here?

Answer (score 1):

Create a mock class that implements the RendererFactory2. Instantiate that in your service.spec.ts